# how to get the data where id is equal to the id of other json data?

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 JSON data. My Objective is to find the id in details.json data and if the id matches with the id of details.json data then it should return the data with contains id else it should return data which should not have an id.

details.json:

```
var categoryArray = [
      {cid: '1', name: 'Category_1'},
      {cid: '2', name: 'Category_2'},
      {cid: '3', name: 'Category_3'},
      {cid: '4', name: 'Category_4'}
     ];
```

sample.json :

```
var sample= {
      {id: '1'},
      {id: '2'},
     };
```

i've written in this way:

```
const allIds = res.data.map(el => { return {id: el.id} }) //getting id in category array
if(id===allIds)
{
return res.data;
}
else {
return res.data!==id
}
```

Can anyone help me to get the data for both the case, if the condition is true then it should return data where id exists otherwise it should return data where id should not exist in the list?

Comment: Do you mean match id from sample.json to detail.json?

Comment: you want both ids which has data in category and ids which dont have data in category to be in seperate arrays ?

Comment: @JoeLloyd - Yes, Correct

Comment: @aravind_reddy - Yes, correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming match ids from sample.json

1. convert sample json to plain array
2. then filter categories json by searching ids included or not

```js
const categoryArray = [
  {cid: '1', name: 'Category_1'},
  {cid: '2', name: 'Category_2'},
  {cid: '3', name: 'Category_3'},
  {cid: '4', name: 'Category_4'}
];

const sample = [
  {id: '1'},
  {id: '2'},
];
 
const idsToFind = sample.map(s => s.id);
 
const categoriesWithIds = categoryArray.filter(category => idsToFind.includes(category.cid));
const categoriesWithoutIds = categoryArray.filter(category => !idsToFind.includes(category.cid));
console.log(categoriesWithIds);
console.log(categoriesWithoutIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created two utilities to get matching and non matching ids.

```js
var categoryArray = [
  { cid: '1', name: 'Category_1' },
  { cid: '2', name: 'Category_2' },
  { cid: '3', name: 'Category_3' },
  { cid: '4', name: 'Category_4' },
]

var sample = [{ id: '1' }, { id: '2' }]

const getMatchingList = (data, ids) => data.filter(cat => ids.some(s => s.id === cat.cid))
const getNonMatchingList = (data, ids) => data.filter(cat => !ids.some(s => s.id === cat.cid))

const matchingList = getMatchingList(categoryArray, sample)
console.log(matchingList)

const nonMatchingList = getNonMatchingList(categoryArray, sample)
console.log(nonMatchingList)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

## Array methods will help here

If you want all the category ids that match sample ids then this is what you want.

```
const categoryArray = [
  {cid: '1', name: 'Category_1'},
  {cid: '2', name: 'Category_2'},
  {cid: '3', name: 'Category_3'},
  {cid: '4', name: 'Category_4'}
];

const sample = [
  {id: '1'},
  {id: '2'},
];

const newArray = categoryArray.filter(({cid}) => {
  return sample.includes(({id}) => id === cid)
})

// output
// const newArray = [
//   {cid: '1', name: 'Category_1'},
//   {cid: '2', name: 'Category_2'},
// ]
```